# Is it possible to create custom config section with assembly in GAC

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, app-config, gac

I have a .NET Library whose dll im putting into GAC. One console app is using this library and defining the custom config section. But it throws excetion at

```
ConfigurationManager.getConfigSection("telemetry")
```

It works perfectly fine when the library dll is in the bin folder. But it throws exception when accessed from GAC. Why is this happening. Any clues? Is there any way to fix this.

My config section is defined as -

```
<configSections>
 <section name="telemetry" type="Com.Example.Telemetry.TelemetryConfig,Com.Example.Telemetry Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=f0c3520fdea11a5a" />
 </configSections>
```

Comment: How have you defined the config section in your web/app config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

Was missing a comma between assembly name and version

```
<configSections>
<section name="telemetry" type="Com.Example.Telemetry.TelemetryConfig,Com.Example.Telemetry, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=f0c3520fdea11a5a" />
 </configSections>
```